# Retrieving data in Java send by JavaScript

Tags: java, javascript, rest

I have a problem with getting the Data send by javascript to java via Rest. I send my Data via ajax.

This is my ajax Method:

```
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: base + "/jira/rest/ticketmeasurementrestresource/1.0/message/" +$filterId +".json",
data: aoColumnSet,  // aoColumnSet is a jsonObject
async: false,
datatype: "json",
success: function(data){
            ;
     aoColumnSet = jQuery.parseJSON(data.value);
    }
});
```

This is my REST Interface

```
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Path("/{key}")
public Response getMessageFrom(@PathParam("key") String key) throws NumberFormatException,  Exception{

    System.out.println("Es klappt mit POST access zu bekommen");

    return null;
}
```

The URL is correct and I can access the method getMessageFrom. I also can extract the data from the URL with @PathParam.

But I don't know where I can get the data send by ajax. How do I get the Jsonobject aoColumSet?

Best Regards,

Steffen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a POJO `AOColumnSet` in Java to match `aoColumnSet`.

Have your method in your controller as:

```
@POST
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML })
@Path("/{key}")
public 
@ResponseBody
Response getMessageFrom(@PathParam("key") String key, @RequestParam AOColumnSet aoColumnSet) throws NumberFormatException,  Exception{
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Maybe my question was a bit unclear. I have no problems with retrieving the data from $filterId which I send in the URL. I have a problem with getting the Json Object aoColumnSet with I post per ajax. I don't know what to do so that I can get this object in my method getMessageFrom